# When applying a type projection, how does type parameters turn into Nothing, Any?, or the type bounds, etc?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, types

I found something in Kotlin that had always been intuitive to me, but I recently realised I can't explain the low level details of this.

Consider what the return type of `x.returnT`, and the parameter types of `consumeT` and `aMoreComplicatedCase` would be in the below code:

```kotlin
val x: Foo<*> = TODO()

class Foo<T> {
    fun returnT(): T = TODO()
    fun consumeT(t: T) {}
    fun aMoreComplicatedCase(func: (T) -> T) {}
}
```

IntelliJ tells me that `x.returnT` returns `Any?`, `consumeT` takes `Nothing`, and `aMoreComplicatedCase` takes `(Any?) -> Nothing`.

[image]

Using the [spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-system.html#use-site-variance), we know that `*` roughly means `out Any?` and `in Nothing` at the same time, and applying [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) (Or maybe this should be called POCI in Kotlin since producer `out` consumer `in`), we know `x` is a producer of `Any?` and a consumer of nothing.

An even more intuitive explanation is that `*` means "we know nothing about what goes in the `<>` of `Foo` at all", and because of that, *of course* `returnT` can return anything, even nullable things. Similarly, *of course* `consumeT` can't take anything - it takes `T`, the exact thing we don't know.

Similar arguments can be applied to cases where it is `out SomeType` or `in SomeType`.

#### Where I am stuck

Having been programming in Java for a long time, I did not expect this result at all. I expected something similar to what IntelliJ would say for the similar Java code:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<?> foo = new Foo<>();
    }
}
class Foo<T> {
    public T returnT() { return null; }
    public void consumeT(T t) { }
    public void aMoreComplicatedCase(Function<T, T> func) { }
}
```

IntelliJ says that `x.returnT` returns a capture of `?`, `consumeT` takes a capture of `?`, and `aMoreComplicatedCase` takes `Function<capture of ?, capture of ?>`:

[image]

I looked around the Kotlin spec and found that Kotlin also have [captured types](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-system.html#type-capturing), which are fresh type variables with certain bounds. **So where does `Nothing` and `Any?` come from?** Or in the case of using `in SomeType` as the projection, `consumeT` will take a `SomeType` instead. **Why is it `SomeType`, but not a capture type with `SomeType` as its subtype?** After all, the spec says in the type capturing section:

> - For a contravariant type argument Ai `in Ai`, if Fi is a covariant type parameter, Ki is an ill-formed type. Otherwise, Ki :> Ai.
> - For a bivariant type argument `⋆`, `kotlin.Nothing` <: Ki <: `kotlin.Any?`

I'm guessing something else happens after type capturing? What is that process called? Or is there a totally different process that is not type capturing going on here?

(I guess there is also the possibility that this is just a matter of "what string representation IntelliJ/kotlinc uses for display, when the type is a captured type" and has nothing to do with the type system itself...)

Comment: I feel like this question is totally out of my expertise level, but how `capture of ?` is different than `Any?`/`Nothing` of Kotlin? Is there something that we can do with `capture of ?`, but we can't with Kotlin equivalent? For example, we still can't do this in Java: `foo.consumeT(foo.returnT())`. For me `capture of ?` sounds like typical, Java-ish gibberish that was just named better in Kotlin :-P But it is quite probable I miss some understanding of what is going on in this case.

Comment: @broot No they are not very different. Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but my question here is mainly about *how* Kotlin renames these "gibberish" capture types (Kotlin clearly still has capture types!) to meaningful things like `Any?` and `Nothing`. I can't find this process documented anywhere. I at least want a name so I can start my search :)

Comment: @broot I know it probably depends on *where* the capture type is (return type, parameter type, etc), and the type projection (`in`, `out`, `*`, nothing), but I can't describe this exact process in words.

Comment: But isn't it as simple as that the `*` depending on the variance is "converted" to these types? This is explained specifically here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#star-projections "For `Foo<out T : TUpper>`, (...) `Foo<*>` is equivalent to `Foo<out TUpper>`. For `Foo<in T>`, (...) `Foo<*>` is equivalent to `Foo<in Nothing>`.

Comment: @broot The use of a star projection here might have made it seem like I don't understand star projections... The question applies equally to other projections. If I say `Foo<out Serializable>`, `x.consumeT` would suddenly take `Nothing`. I understand intuitively that this is because `Foo<out Serializable>` is now a "producer of `T`s", so it doesn't take in `T`s anymore. However, in a more complicated case like `aMoreComplicatedCase` (or even more complicated than that), I cannot predict what its parameter type will be for `x: Foo<out Serializable>` until I see IntelliJ's autocomplete.

Comment: After I see the answer, I can usually reason (with some handwaving) why it is this way, but I want to know the process by which Kotlin does this "capture types -> actual types" transformation, so that I can actually predict this and explain the process to others.